# How can I integrate chat with quickblox sdk in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, quickblox

I want to use QuickBlox for creating a chat app in react native. I don't know from where to start. Just need to know is there any library that provide quickblox chat for react native or creating bridge between ios/android and react native is only option.

Comment: There are some NPM packages out there (like this one https://github.com/vinayr/react-native-quickblox). But if I was you I would do a native bridge to their iOS SDK in order to properly handle notifications etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know QuickBlox does not support React Native officially. 
So, if you need it to be done with QuickBlox, you'll end up using some third-party library.

If you are considering alternatives to QuickBlox, you can try another provider who has React native support added. 
You can try one of the following providers:

- [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) - has React Native [chat and video chat code samples](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/react-native)
- [Applozic](https://www.applozic.com) - has React Native chat, but does not support video calls already

Answer (score 0):

QuickBlox has recently released ReactNative SDK, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/react-native-quick-start) and the [official chat sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-react-native-samples)